# Union member data alignment

Tags: c, unions

I'm having some problem with data alignment in a union, which I can't seem to figure out. Using a union similar to the one below, there seems to be some data offset at the union's base address.

```
typedef union MyUnion
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        uint16_t val_1;
        uint8_t  val_2;
        uint8_t  val_3;
    }data;
    uint8_t data_array[4];
}MyUnion;
```

At some point I've filled the struct in with data,

```
my_union.data.val_1 = 65535;
my_union.data.val_2 = 0;
my_union.data.val_3 = 0;
```

I then try to access the data using the array. What I expect to see at the base address of the array is the first byte of val_1, 255. However, when accessing the data in the array, it seems to be offset from the struct's base by 1 byte.

```
printf("Bytes of struct: %#08x\n", my_union.data.val_1);
printf("Bytes of array:  %#08x\n", my_array.data_array[0]);
```

No matter what values I put in the above results in output similar to this.

```
Bytes of struct:  0x00ffff
Bytes of array:   0x0000ff
```

I first thought that the members may be offset somehow and were referencing different memory address's, but when I print their addresses, they are the same.

Also, if I print the following values they are equal.

```
printf("Bytes of struct: %#08x\n", my_union.data);
printf("Bytes of array:  %#08x\n", *(my_array.data_array - 1) );
```

Output:

```
    Bytes of struct:  0x00ffff
    Bytes of array:   0x00ffff
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure it out, at the moment. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: You should be getting errors. Post a sscce, instead of snippets of code.

Comment: How 'similar to the one below' is the union you're actually using? Can you actually reproduce the problem with the union you show in the question?  Can you show the complete but minimal code that compiles and the output it produces, and identify the compiler and platform on which you are running it?  Your choice of values is not very good for diagnosing the problem; you should consider assigning (for example), 0xFEDC to `val_1` and perhaps 0xBA to `val_2` and 0x89 to `val_3`. See MCTRE/MCVE [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's fairly different and the struct contains some strange data type, i.e. bit-field structs, but the first member of the struct in the union is an unsigned short. I'm using MinGW GCC 4.6.2. The platform is a RISC soft processor from Altera called the Nios II. Sorry about the values in the example. I've used ones in which I can track the bytes separately and it shows the behavior above. The array data is always offset by one byte from the struct data.

Comment: OK; you've definitely got a more complicated problem.  So, you need to produce minimal code that reproduces your problem in your environment — see my answer for a possible outline — and then show that code, the actual output, the expected output, and an explanation of why you think the actual output is wrong and the expected output is right. Is the RISC processor big-endian or little-endian?  I observe that your comment "I've used [values] in which I can track the bytes separately" is inaccurate; you cannot tell the two 0xFF bytes from each other, nor can you tell the two 0x00 bytes apart.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, what I meant to say was I didn't use 0xFF for the bytes, while debugging. I actually used byte values which I could see. I basically did the same thing you did in your example in the environment. I'll post the example shortly. Byte order is little-endian. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Run on a little-endian machine (Intel Core i7, Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks, GCC 4.8.2), the following program:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union MyUnion
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        uint16_t val_1;
        uint8_t  val_2;
        uint8_t  val_3;
    } data;
    uint8_t data_array[4];  // NB: was unint8_t!!!
} MyUnion;

int main(void)
{
    MyUnion my_union;

    my_union.data.val_1 = 0xFEDC;
    my_union.data.val_2 = 0xBA;
    my_union.data.val_3 = 0x98;

    printf("val_1 = 0x%.4" PRIX16 "; val_2 = 0x%.2" PRIX8 "; val_3 = 0x%.2" PRIX8 "\n",
           my_union.data.val_1, my_union.data.val_2, my_union.data.val_3);

    char const *pad = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(my_union.data_array); i++)
    {
        printf("%sarray[%zu] = 0x%.2" PRIX8, pad, i, my_union.data_array[i]);
        pad = "; ";
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

produces the output shown:

```
val_1 = 0xFEDC; val_2 = 0xBA; val_3 = 0x98
array[0] = 0xDC; array[1] = 0xFE; array[2] = 0xBA; array[3] = 0x98
```

This is very much what I'd expect.  You'd get different output on a big-endian machine (anything but Intel, more or less).

You need to adapt this code (or something very similar) to demonstrate whatever problem you perceive you have, and show the modified code and the actual output and your explanation of what you expect and why you expect the different output.

Comment: This is exactly what I expected to see. I've run through the array, as well, and I get the same byte offset. I saw your other comment too. I'll reply to it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitively wrong:

```
printf("Bytes of array:  %#08x\n", my_array.data_array);
```

you are printing the address of the first element of the array, instead of the contents, which is what seems to interest you.

Printing a pointer should use the `%p` format, anyhow, so a decent compiler should give you a warning.

To print the contents of the array, you'd have to print each element of it. The correct format specifier for `uint8_t` (not `unint8_t` !) is the macro `PRIx8`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
printf("Bytes of struct: %#08x\n", *(uint32_t*)&my_union.data);
printf("Bytes of array:  %#08x\n", *(uint32_t*)my_union.data_array);
```